# R: Apply different filters based on variable

Tags: r, date, filter

From the dataset below, I want to keep the row first date of the month for January, but for the other months I want to keep only the rows with the last date of the month. Like this:

```
2021-01-01 493 jan 2021
2021-02-28 707 feb 2021
2021-03-31 688 mrt 2021
2021-04-30 1217 apr 2021
2021-05-31 1237 mei 2021
```

I've tried the following:

```
if (str_detect(Month2, "jan" ) { 
    filter(Date == min(Date))
  } else filter(Date == max(Date))
```

But no luck. Then I tried to create a new (numeric) variable for the if statement:

```
mutate(JANDECFIX = case_when(
    str_detect(Month2, "jan") ~ 1,
    TRUE ~ 2
  )   
         ) %>%
 
  if (JANDECFIX == 1 ) { 
    filter(Date == min(Date))
  } else filter(Date == max(Date))
```

But then got the following error:

```
Error in if (.) JANDECFIX == 1 else { : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (.) JANDECFIX == 1 else { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

How can I make this work to end up with the example in the beginning?

df:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(18722, 18723, 18721, 18653, 
18654, 18650, 18652, 18649, 18758, 18651, 18724, 18737, 18738, 
18775, 18639, 18655, 18749, 18778, 18747, 18772, 18750, 18771, 
18748, 18632, 18640, 18631, 18764, 18690, 18689, 18773, 18763, 
18777, 18646, 18647, 18729, 18757, 18725, 18759, 18680, 18633, 
18769, 18774, 18736, 18661, 18648, 18739, 18730, 18762, 18660, 
18694, 18751, 18776, 18656, 18659, 18761, 18745, 18746, 18707, 
18687, 18688, 18770, 18695, 18681, 18693, 18740, 18638, 18728, 
18676, 18634, 18677, 18641, 18726, 18678, 18743, 18760, 18709, 
18742, 18692, 18657, 18679, 18702, 18720, 18691, 18645, 18662, 
18683, 18635, 18658, 18765, 18701, 18673, 18663, 18706, 18741, 
18682, 18719, 18642, 18731, 18699, 18675, 18755, 18698, 18753, 
18700, 18766, 18732, 18696, 18756, 18668, 18684, 18705, 18686, 
18636, 18715, 18744, 18637, 18717, 18630, 18644, 18685, 18718, 
18735, 18664, 18767, 18727, 18703, 18713, 18674, 18733, 18754, 
18710, 18666, 18768, 18697, 18643, 18667, 18714, 18716, 18734, 
18704, 18752, 18711, 18669, 18670, 18708, 18629, 18672, 18671, 
18712, 18628, 18665), class = "Date"), UPV = c(3358L, 2843L, 
2771L, 2358L, 2035L, 2000L, 1965L, 1664L, 1638L, 1622L, 1578L, 
1572L, 1525L, 1479L, 1448L, 1360L, 1332L, 1237L, 1217L, 1207L, 
1182L, 1181L, 1180L, 1177L, 1163L, 1151L, 1123L, 1118L, 1110L, 
1090L, 1071L, 1068L, 1058L, 1053L, 1049L, 1048L, 1043L, 1038L, 
1031L, 1030L, 1025L, 1014L, 1012L, 1008L, 1006L, 996L, 991L, 
990L, 979L, 974L, 972L, 964L, 961L, 957L, 953L, 944L, 936L, 917L, 
914L, 909L, 900L, 894L, 880L, 878L, 873L, 869L, 862L, 862L, 857L, 
857L, 848L, 844L, 842L, 839L, 832L, 829L, 828L, 826L, 825L, 825L, 
822L, 819L, 813L, 805L, 796L, 795L, 793L, 787L, 784L, 778L, 776L, 
775L, 775L, 774L, 768L, 763L, 754L, 754L, 744L, 738L, 734L, 733L, 
729L, 726L, 719L, 716L, 715L, 715L, 714L, 713L, 708L, 707L, 707L, 
702L, 693L, 690L, 688L, 672L, 672L, 671L, 667L, 662L, 661L, 658L, 
657L, 649L, 645L, 633L, 631L, 624L, 622L, 612L, 608L, 606L, 595L, 
584L, 584L, 582L, 579L, 568L, 568L, 563L, 550L, 547L, 539L, 524L, 
522L, 509L, 497L, 493L, 400L), Month2 = structure(c(16L, 16L, 
16L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 17L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 13L, 
13L, 17L, 17L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 17L, 15L, 
15L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 17L, 16L, 17L, 14L, 13L, 17L, 
17L, 16L, 14L, 13L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 17L, 13L, 14L, 
17L, 16L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 17L, 15L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 13L, 16L, 
14L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 16L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 15L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 17L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 14L, 16L, 13L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 17L, 15L, 17L, 15L, 17L, 16L, 
15L, 17L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 13L, 15L, 13L, 13L, 
14L, 16L, 16L, 14L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 15L, 14L, 
17L, 15L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 15L, 17L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 
13L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 13L, 14L), .Label = c("jan 2020", "feb 2020", 
"mrt 2020", "apr 2020", "mei 2020", "jun 2020", "jul 2020", "aug 2020", 
"sep 2020", "okt 2020", "nov 2020", "dec 2020", "jan 2021", "feb 2021", 
"mrt 2021", "apr 2021", "mei 2021"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-151L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(Date) %>%
  group_by(Month2) %>%
  slice(if(grepl('jan|dec', Month2)) 1L else n()) %>%
  ungroup

#  Date         UPV Month2  
#  <date>     <int> <fct>   
#1 2021-01-01   493 jan 2021
#2 2021-02-28   707 feb 2021
#3 2021-03-31   688 mrt 2021
#4 2021-04-30  1217 apr 2021
#5 2021-05-31  1237 mei 2021
```